# Accessing object data slicing numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

So i'm working on optimizing some python code by using numpy arrays instead of for each loops. Is there any way to access fields from a class during slicing of a numpy array?

```
class foo:

    the_int = 0

    def __init__(self, i):
        self.bar = i

one, two = foo(5), foo(10)
ar = array([one, two])

int_array = ar[0:2].the_int

#I want int_array = [5, 10]
```

If that isn't possible in that manner, how would I efficiently generate my "int_array" variable without using a for each loop to loop through "ar", gather "the_int" from each entry?

Thanks,
Kyle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using a numpy array to store PyObjects? You won't get the performance improvement you think. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232597/storing-python-objects-in-a-python-list-vs-a-fixed-length-numpy-array).

Using a list, you can use a list comprehension instead:

```
class foo:

    the_int = 0

    def __init__(self, i):
        self.bar = i

one, two = foo(5), foo(10)

ar = [one, two]

int_array = [i.bar for i in ar[0:2]]
```

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Didn't realize that numpy arrays shouldn't store objects. So there's no way with objects to avoid the for each loop?

Comment: even though the syntax is similar, the list comprehension I have used is not actually a for loop

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that. It's significantly faster that my original for loop. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Something, `for loop` or otherwise, has to query each object (or the list or array) for its `bar` attribute.  Your object has been coded in Python, so that query is a Python operation.